# I passed a function (not a predicate) to Array.Filter and it returned me the whole array - How does that work?

Tags: javascript

Instead of passing predicate to Array.filter, I instead passed a function that modified individual student objects and the filter returned me the whole array. What's happening here ?
Shouldn't filter only accept predicates and should evaluate if it matches the condition or not

```js
 const students = [
  {
    name: "Anna",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [4.5, 3.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Dennis",
    sex: "m",
    country: "Germany",
    grades: [5, 1.5, 4]
  },
  {
    name: "Martha",
    sex: "f",
    grades: [5, 4, 2.5, 3]
  },
  {
    name: "Brock",
    sex: "m",
    grades: [4, 3, 2]
  }
];

 console.log(students.filter(s=>s.sex='m'));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Array Filter</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your callback:

```js
s=>s.sex='m'
```

always returns a truthy value: `'m'`.

The expression result of an assignment is the value that was assigned.

```js
let a;
const expressionResult = (a = 5);
console.log(expressionResult);
```

Since the value returned from the `.filter` is truthy, all elements in the original array are included, because all elements had a truthy value returned from the callback.

What you probably want is to return whether or not sex is m, like so:

```js
students.filter(s => s.sex === 'm');
```

If you want to prevent yourself from making these kinds of mistakes, consider using a linter like ESLint and the [no-return-assign rule](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign).